# Scrollable Layout in Vaadin Flow

Tags: scrollview, vaadin, vaadin-flow

In Vaadin Flow, there exists no Component that is essentially a Scrollable Layout.
In Vaadin 8, this was done by the [Panel](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/layout/layout-panel.html).

Is there a way to achieve a scrollable Component in Vaadin Flow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:** I have now published an add-on [here](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/scrolllayout/2.0.0) that provides the class **`VerticalScrollLayout`**, and also the class **`HorizontalScrollLayout`**. If there are suggestions for improvements, feel free to contact me or comment here.

---

Yes it is possible, although there is no existing Component that does it automatically.
The way to go is placing a VerticalLayout (for a *vertical* scroll bar) inside another component, and setting the `display` property of that VerticalLayout from `flex` to `block`. (credits to Diego Sanz Villafruela in the [vaadin forum](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17192835/17193246))

I have made my own `VerticalScrollLayout` class that does it all for you, so that **using it in a view is as easy as using a simple VerticalLayout**

```
public class VerticalScrollLayout extends VerticalLayout {
    private VerticalLayout content;

    public VerticalScrollLayout(){
        preparePanel();
    }

    public VerticalScrollLayout(Component... children){
        preparePanel();
        this.add(children);
    }

    private void preparePanel() {
        setWidth("100%");
        setHeight("100%");
        getStyle().set("overflow", "auto");

        content = new VerticalLayout();
        content.getStyle().set("display", "block");
        content.setWidth("100%");
        content.setPadding(false);
        super.add(content);
    }

    public VerticalLayout getContent(){
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Component... components){
        content.add(components);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Component... components){
        content.remove(components);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeAll(){
        content.removeAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void addComponentAsFirst(Component component) {
        content.addComponentAtIndex(0, component);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, that you can get some unpredictable behavior when combining a flex container with overflow: auto. A safer approach is to wrap the flex container and let the wrapping element handle the scroll.

Comment: yeah I know too little about flex to know what exactly you mean by that, but I guess this is the reason why this no longer works in the freshly-released 14.1.0

Comment: @Jouni I believe to remember seeing an official scrollable layout being planned to release in 14.2 or 14.3? Until then, could you explain what you mean by that, or give me a link where I can read up on that? it would be much appreciated

Comment: I said it would no longer work in 14.1.0 but this is not true. I had [a strange issue](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17984188/17984189) that broke my scrollable layout but it was not caused by 14.1.0.

Answer (score 3):

There is now an official component for scrolling:

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/scroller